# Difficult data manipulation to fill values in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have what appears to be a fairly difficult to vectorize / speed up problem at hand. I am able to solve the problem with a nested for-loop that scales slowly. The data I'm working with is NBA possession data, and I'm analyzing it over multiple NBA seasons (100K - 1M) rows, which is very slow (multiple minutes) in my nested for loop. I created test data to highlight the problem:

```
mydf = data.frame(id1 = c(100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150),
              id2 = c(110, 110, 110, 122, 122, 122),
              P1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
              P2 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
              O1 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
              O2 = c(5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6), 
              A1 = 0, 
              A2 = 0, 
              A3 = 0, 
              A4 = 0, 
              A5 = 0,
              A6 = 0)
```

There are 6 unique users in this dataframe, (1-6), and their IDs appear in columns P1, P2, O1, and O2. Each user also gets its own column, (A1-A6). Each time a user appears in a row in columns P1 or P2, it's respective column gets a 1. Each time a user appears in a row in columns O1 or O2, it's respective column gets a -1. My for-loop for solving this problem is as follows:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mydf)) {
  for (j in 3:4) {
    tmp = paste0("A",as.character(mydf[i,j]))
    mydf[i, which(colnames(mydf) == tmp)] = 1
  }

  for (j in 5:6) {
    tmp = paste0("A",as.character(mydf[i,j]))
    mydf[i, which(colnames(mydf) == tmp)] = -1
  }
}
```

My actual dataframe has P1-P5, O1-O5, and roughly 300 unique player IDs. Any thoughts on how I can speed this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About twice as fast as your version on the sample data set; the downside is that you need to specify the number of players

```
for (i in 1:6) { 
  mydf[paste0("A", i)] <- (i==mydf$P1 | i==mydf$P2) * 1 - 1*
                                   (i==mydf$O1 | i==mydf$O2)
}
```

This is only a little faster on the sample, but is easier to adapt to different numbers of P/O columns:

```
playercols <- function(mydf, nplayers, plus, minus) {
  for (i in 1:nplayers) {
    mydf[paste0("A", i)] <- rowSums(i==mydf[, plus]) - 
      rowSums(i==mydf[, minus])
  }
  mydf
}

playercols(mydf, 6, 3:4, 5:6)
```

Comment: NB, I'm not quite sure what the expected outcome is if one player id is in multiple P/O columns. The first version has a max of 1, any negative and any positive will yield 0. The second instead adds up all the +/-1s.

Comment: Hey Chris, appreciate the help with this. It looks like the first approach should have single bars | rather than double bars ||. The double bars return a single value, whereas they should be returning a vector of values for each iteration of the loop (since your loop fills an entire column with each loop) - I've edited the code above with single bars to reflect this.

Comment: also, it looks like the playercols function works better for some reason when I add return(mydf) between the two closing curly braces.

Comment: Went with this as the accepted answer, even though it has a for-loop, because I like the function's ability to adapt to # of players. Also, the for-loop loops over players (which has a relative cap), does not loop over rows which is what I was trying to avoid. A lot of great answers in this thread, thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your sample data, this should work:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(tibble)

mydf.calculated <- mydf %>%

  # make row names explicit so that we can join back by row later
  rownames_to_column("row.id") %>%
  select(row.id, starts_with("P"), starts_with("O")) %>%

  # convert to long format & define calculation based on whether P or O
  gather(operation, A, -row.id) %>%
  mutate(calculation = ifelse(grepl("P", operation), 1, -1)) %>%

  # if there are multiple P and/or O operations on the same user in the same row,
  # collapse into final calculated result
  group_by(row.id, A) %>%
  summarise(calculation = sum(calculation)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%

  # spread calculated results to respective user columns
  mutate(A = paste0("A", A)) %>%
  spread(A, calculation, fill = 0) %>%

  # sort in original row order
  arrange(row.id) %>% select(-row.id)

# combine results
cbind(mydf %>% select(-starts_with("A")),
      mydf.calculated)

  id1 id2 P1 P2 O1 O2 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
1 100 110  1  2  4  5  1  1  0 -1 -1  0
2 100 110  1  2  4  5  1  1  0 -1 -1  0
3 100 110  1  2  4  6  1  1  0 -1  0 -1
4 150 122  1  3  4  6  1  0  1 -1  0 -1
5 150 122  2  3  4  6  0  1  1 -1  0 -1
6 150 122  2  3  4  6  0  1  1 -1  0 -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Not especially efficient but this works:

```
cA <- col(mydf[,7:12])
mydf[,7:12] <- (cA==mydf$P1)+(cA==mydf$P2)-(cA==mydf$O1)-(cA==mydf$O2)

mydf
  id1 id2 P1 P2 O1 O2 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
1 100 110  1  2  4  5  1  1  0 -1 -1  0
2 100 110  1  2  4  5  1  1  0 -1 -1  0
3 100 110  1  2  4  6  1  1  0 -1  0 -1
4 150 122  1  3  4  6  1  0  1 -1  0 -1
5 150 122  2  3  4  6  0  1  1 -1  0 -1
6 150 122  2  3  4  6  0  1  1 -1  0 -1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - I should have noted in my example that in my actual data, the user IDs are not sequential. My example uses 1-6 but my data is a random 400 IDs all somewhere in the range of 1 - 5000. I will try to edit your code to reflect this.

Comment: @Canovice - I've just added a modified version of this that should solve the non-sequential ID problem.

Answer (score 1):

Having measured the runtimes of the other answers, this might be the fastest yet. It's a modified version of @Glen_b's answer that's flexible for non-sequential IDs:

```
vals <- gsub("^A","",names(mydf)[grep("^A",names(mydf))]),
cA <- data.frame(sapply(vals,function(i) rep(i,length(vals)))),
mydf[,grep("A",names(mydf))] <- (cA==mydf$P1)+(cA==mydf$P2)-(cA==mydf$O1)-(cA==mydf$O2)
```

Output:

```
  id1 id2 P1 P2 O1 O2 A1 A7 A3 A8 A5 A10
1 100 110  1  7 10  5  1  1  0  0 -1  -1
2 100 110  1  7 10  5  1  1  0  0 -1  -1
3 100 110  5  7  1  8 -1  1  0 -1  1   0
4 150 122  1 10  7  8  1 -1  0 -1  0   1
5 150 122  3  3  5  7  0 -1  2  0 -1   0
6 150 122  3  8  3  5  0  0  0  1 -1   0
```

Here's the sample data I edited to include the non-sequential IDs:

```
mydf = data.frame(id1 = c(100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150),
              id2 = c(110, 110, 110, 122, 122, 122),
              P1 = c(1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 3),
              P2 = c(7, 7, 7, 10, 3, 8),
              O1 = c(10, 10, 1, 7, 5, 3),
              O2 = c(5, 5, 8, 8, 7, 5), 
              A1 = 0, 
              A7 = 0, 
              A3 = 0, 
              A8 = 0, 
              A5 = 0,
              A10 = 0)
```

To measure the runtime, you can use a package like microbenchmark:

```
require(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  vals <- gsub("^A","",names(mydf)[grep("^A",names(mydf))]),
  cA <- data.frame(sapply(vals,function(i) rep(i,length(vals)))),
  mydf[,grep("A",names(mydf))] <- (cA==mydf$P1)+(cA==mydf$P2)-(cA==mydf$O1)-(cA==mydf$O2)
)

Unit: microseconds
     min        lq       mean    median       uq      max neval cld
  19.263   27.4365   44.48546   37.4500   48.158  150.556   100   a  
 460.698  555.1930  869.30677  692.5255 1004.787 3343.197   100   b 
1378.804 1656.6080 2815.49635 2140.1545 3216.846 8664.538   100   c
```